# polynomial of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> $A\in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{K})$ and $\gamma\ne 0$ such that $B=\gamma A$
>
> 1. Compare the spectrum of $A$ and $B$
> 2. $P\in \mathbb{K}_n[X]$ compare $P_A$ and $P_B$
> 3. Compare $m_A$ and $m_B$ (minimum polynomials)
>
>    ---

**Question 1**

Let $\mathcal{X}_A(x)=|A-xI_n|$ and $\text{Sp}(A)=\{\lambda_1,\cdots, \lambda_p\}$

$\mathcal{X}_B(x)=|B-xI_n|=|\gamma A-xI_n|=|\gamma(A-\dfrac{x}{\gamma}I_n)|=\gamma^n|A-\dfrac{x}{\gamma}I_n)|=\gamma^n\mathcal{X}_A(\dfrac{x}{\gamma})$

$$\mathcal{X}_A(\dfrac{x}{\gamma})=0 \iff \dfrac{x}{\gamma}=\lambda_i\iff x=\gamma \lambda_i$$

So $\text{Sp}(B)=\{\gamma\lambda_1,\cdots, \gamma\lambda_p\}$

**Question 2**

Let $P\in \mathbb{K}_n[X]$

$P_A=\sum\limits_{k=0}^na_0A^k$ and $[x_i]$ such that $A[x_i]=\lambda_i[x_i]$

$P_A([x_i])=\sum\limits_{k=0}^na_0(A[x_i])^k=\sum\limits_{k=0}^na_0\lambda_i^kx_i=x_iP(\lambda_i)$

So the spectrum of $P_A$ is $\bigg\{P(\lambda_i)\bigg\}_{i=1}^p$, I deduce tat the spectrum of $P_B$ is $\bigg\{P(\gamma\lambda_i)\bigg\}_{i=1}^p$

**Question 3**

Since $m_A|\mathcal{X}_A$ and $\mathcal{X}_B=\gamma^n\mathcal{X}_A(\frac{X}{\gamma})$ then $m_A(\frac{X}{\gamma})|\mathcal{X}_B$

**And now it misses one argument to conclude $m_B(X)=m_A(\frac{X}{\gamma})$**

So my question : Is that correct (question 1 and 2) and what is the right argument to conclude at the third question?

Comment: $m_B(\gamma x)$ vanishes at $A$ and $m_A(x/\gamma)$ vanishes at $B$. Therefore $m_A(x)|m_B(\gamma x)$ and $m_B(x)|m_A(x/\gamma)$. Therefore $m_A$ and $m_B$ have the same degree. It follows that $\gamma^nm_A(x/\gamma)$ is another monic polynomial of the same degree as $m_B$ that also vanishes at $B$. So, it is $m_B$.

Comment: ok thanks for this answer